# error initializing mockito, everytime and for any test cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Pretty much spent the entire day fighting this. It doesn't matter what kind of tests/class/interface I use, I get pretty much the same exception. Here's the stackerror:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability;
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:167)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:161)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:58)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1410)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Infact, I don't even understand why the powermock library is involved. It does get compiled as I was trying to mock some final classes, but that was hours ago!

Here's an actual set of files I'm trying to utilize:

```
public class ClassA {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage(){

        message="classA";
        return message;

    }
}

public class ClassB {

    private ClassA myClass;

    public ClassB(ClassA aClass){
        this.myClass=aClass;
    }

    public ClassA getClassA(){
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

and the testing class:

```
package com.icidigital.services

import com.icidigital.users.ClassA
import com.icidigital.users.ClassB
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner
/**
 * Created by apil.tamang on 7/28/15.
 */
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class TestSimplestMock {

    ClassB classB;

    @Mock
    ClassA mockA;

    @Before
    public void setup(){


        classB=new ClassB(mockA);

        Mockito.when(classB.getClassA()).thenReturn(null);

    }

    @Test
    public void testA(){

        ClassA obj=classB.getClassA();

        assert(obj==null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you rebuilt the project?  As in, completely razed your class files and attempted to reconstruct it?

Comment: I did a couple times. Anyways, this time right after I posted this issue, I removed the testCompile for the powermockito library, rebuilt the configutations, then the build, and it worked... except for I'm getting another cryptic error.. Mockito complains of a MissingMethoException for 'getClassA()' although it really is defined for ClassB. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in your follow-up comment to go on. I would post a separate question with the full trace, and link to this one.

Comment: I removed the dependency for power-mockito from my pom and everything worked.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible for third-party plugins to register custom `MockMaker` implementations that create classes differently to the default behavior via Mockito's SPI. As a part of the specified behavior, since Mockito 2.0, a `MockMaker` can decide if a class is mockable, such as `final` classes in the case of PowerMock. In order to integrate such a custom behavior, PowerMock registers a custom `MockMaker` that is then used by Mockito.

In Mockito 2.0, the API for a custom `MockMaker` had to be extended but `PowerMock` does not yet adapt the API extensions. Therefore, this new method is not yet implemented by the PowerMock `MockMaker` what results in an `AbstractMethodError`.

Comment: So...is it possible to configure Mockito to prevent MockMacker extensions?

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: PowerMock offers a mockito2 version. This integration also works with Mockito 3.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same Error. For me it helped to include

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;
```

instead of Mockitos `mock()` and `spy()` methods. `@Mock` remained the same.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer was given by *Raphael Winterhalter*. But currently **PowerMockito** team is working on bringing support of Mockito2+
Latest stable version for now is RC4

```
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC4'
```

It compiles but there are still a lot of issues

Here is Wiki page about Mockito 2 support
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-(Maven)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is what you are trying to do. But if you are trying to return null whenever getClassA is called, then you should mock object of type ClassB! (since getClassA is a method of that class).

Comment: Yapp realized that in just a little while. But the original issue still remains: why the conflict between the mockito and powermock runners? Does that mean I may never have both the powermock and mockito libraries loaded at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when working with mockito-core:jar:2.18.3 and powermock-api-mockito:1.6.3.
It worked for me when I downgraded to mockito-core:jar:2.0.5-beta.

Answer (score 0):

There are version incompatibility: with the following versions in the pom everything works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```